# Alternative for nested weights in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display eleven rows containing four `TextView` items each, that's a total of 44 textviews in one screen.

I didn't want the difference in screen sizes of different handsets to cause issues with this so I thought of using nested weights. I'd have a `LinearLayout` with a horizontal orientation, containing four `TextView` items with their weights adjusted so they'd fit properly on the screen in one line. I'd have eleven such `LinearLayout` items nested within a parent `LinearLayout` with a vertical orientation and I'd adjust the weights of the inner `LinearLayout` items so that they would all fit on the screen.

However, this does not seem to work. It says that nested weights are bad for performance.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using a GridView or GridLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the text views dynamically you can go for **listview** with custom adapters.
If you want it to be static, then you can go for **tablelayout** with each table rows having four textviews each. If you are not satisfied, I can give you an example layout also..

Sample TableLayout

Comment: Can you please give me an example for tablelayout?

Answer (score 1):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow>
      <!-- Column 1 -->
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tbl_txt1"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@color/red"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
         android:padding="10dip"
         android:layout_margin="4dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="Column 1" />

      <!-- Column 2 -->
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tbl_txt2"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@color/red"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
         android:padding="10dip"
         android:layout_margin="4dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="Column 2" />

      <!-- Column 3 -->
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tbl_txt3"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@color/red"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
         android:padding="10dip"
         android:layout_margin="4dip"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```